# Use a particular CA for a SSL connection

Tags: c#, validation, ssl, x509certificate, ca

I'm reading through [Support Certificates In Your Applications With The .NET Framework 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163454.aspx) trying to determine how to set a CA for a SSL connection.

Around half-way down the article under [Validating Certificates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163454.aspx#S6), MSDN presents some code:

```
static void ValidateCert(X509Certificate2 cert)
{
    X509Chain chain = new X509Chain();

    // check entire chain for revocation 
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationFlag = X509RevocationFlag.EntireChain;

    // check online and offline revocation lists
    chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.Online | 
                                           X509RevocationMode.Offline;

    // timeout for online revocation list 
    chain.ChainPolicy.UrlRetrievalTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);

    // no exceptions, check all properties
    chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

    // modify time of verification
    chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationTime = new DateTime(1999, 1, 1);

    chain.Build(cert);
    if (chain.ChainStatus.Length != 0)
        Console.WriteLine(chain.ChainStatus[0].Status);
    }
```

Then later:

```
// override default certificate policy
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(VerifyServerCertificate);
```

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious. For example, I don't want a callback - I just want to say, "establish a SSL connection, and here's the one CA to trust".  But I don't see that in the code above.

[`X509Chain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509chain(v=vs.110).aspx) does not appear to have an `add` method to add a CA or root of trust. Shouldn't the CA be set before the callback? But I don't see that in the code above.

In Java, it would be done with a `TrustManager` (or `TrustManagerFactory`) after loading the particular CA you want to use (for an example, see [Use PEM Encoded CA Cert on filesystem directly for HTTPS request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22493997/use-pem-encode-ca-cert-on-filesystem-directly-for-https-request)).

**Question**: How does one set a CA to use for an SSL connection in .Net or C#?

Answer (score 2):

The following code will avoid the Windows certificate stores and validate the chain with a CA on the filesystem.

The name of the function does not matter. Below, `VerifyServerCertificate` is the same callback as `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` in `SslStream` class. It can also be used for the `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` in `ServicePointManager`.

```
static bool VerifyServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    try
    {
        String CA_FILE = "ca-cert.der";
        X509Certificate2 ca = new X509Certificate2(CA_FILE);

        X509Chain chain2 = new X509Chain();
        chain2.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore.Add(ca);

        // Check all properties
        chain2.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.NoFlag;

        // This setup does not have revocation information
        chain2.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;

        // Build the chain
        chain2.Build(new X509Certificate2(certificate));

        // Are there any failures from building the chain?
        if (chain2.ChainStatus.Length == 0)
            return false;

        // If there is a status, verify the status is NoError
        bool result = chain2.ChainStatus[0].Status == X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError;
        Debug.Assert(result == true);

        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have *not* figured out how to use this chain (`chain2` below) by default such that there's no need for the callback. That is, install it on the ssl socket and the connection will "just work". And I have *not* figured out how install it such that its passed into the callback. That is, I have to build the chain for each invocation of the callback. I think these are architectural defects in .Net, but I might be missing something obvious.

Comment: A local CA certificate is one that can't be validated or revoked. Only recently, the Heartbleed exploit exposed the certificates on numerous sites, causing massive revocations - and many sites are still unsafe. Your solution would be valid if you loaded the certificate from its URL source instead of the local drive, ensuring it is valid. To avoid the performance penalty you can cache the certificate but then - that's what Windows Certificate store already does for you.

Comment: if (chain2.ChainStatus.Length == 0) should return False, not true